# how to rotate a bufferd-image in java?

Tags: java, image-processing, bufferedimage

I am having a bufferd-image i.e:

```
  BufferedImage buffer = ImageIO.read(new File(file));
```

now i want to rotate it.. So how i can do it??

Previously i have used the image format i.e:

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(new File(file));
```

and could easily rotate a image using:

```
   AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
   at.rotate(0.5 * angle * Math.PI, width/2, height/2);
```

But i dont noe how to do it with the bufferd-image?? Can you help me??

Comment: AffineTransform will work fine if used on a Graphics2D object derived from your BufferedImage, but you'd better take care to choose the correct center of rotation and clipping if the image isn't square.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example:

```
BufferedImage buffer = ImageIO.read(new File(file));
AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
//tx.scale(scalex, scaley);
//tx.shear(shiftx, shifty);
//tx.translate(x, y);
tx.rotate(radians, buffer.getWidth()/2, buffer.getHeight()/2);

AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
buffer = op.filter(buffer, null);
```

See also:

- [Rotate an image in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156518/rotate-an-image-in-java)
- [Rotating BufferedImage instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918482/java-rotating-bufferedimages)
- [AffineTransform truncates image, what do I wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719473/affinetransform-truncates-image-what-do-i-wrong/8720123#8720123)

Comment: The two links at bottom show how to recenter if needed.  This question should probably be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: You can add my answer to your links: [affinetransform-truncates-image-what-do-i-wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719473/affinetransform-truncates-image-what-do-i-wrong/8720123#8720123)