# AffineTransformOp.filter strange behavior when rotating by non 0,90,180,270 degrees

Tags: java, graphics, affinetransform

so I am programming a game and I'm trying to get an enemy to look at a player as the player moves around. I try to rotate the image using this code:

```
public static BufferedImage rotateImage(BufferedImage image, double radians) {
    //Rotate the given image by the angle
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(radians,image.getWidth()/2,image.getHeight()/2);
    AffineTransformOp atOp = new AffineTransformOp(at,AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
    return atOp.filter(image,null);
}
```

The image is updated here:

```
public void rotateEnemyImage() {
    double radians = Math.asin(xVel/Math.sqrt((yVel*yVel+xVel*xVel)));
    if (Math.abs(currentRotation - radians) > MINIMUMROTATION) {
        enemyImage = cemeteryfuntimes.Code.Shared.Utilities.rotateImage(enemyImage, radians - currentRotation);
        currentRotation = radians;
    }
}
```

(I know the equation for calculating radians isn't quite correct I'm still working on that, but its hard to tinker with when the enemy isn't being drawn correctly)

And I draw the image using this code:

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
    g.drawImage(enemyImage, Math.round(xSide+xPos), Math.round(ySide+yPos), null);
}
```

(xSide and ySide are just constants for the game border)

This code works for changing the direction the player is looking:

```
public void rotatePlayerImage(int direction) {
    //Rotate the image of the player
    int rotationAngle = shootDirection[direction];
    playerImage =        cemeteryfuntimes.Code.Shared.Utilities.rotateImage(playerImage,Math.toRadians(rotationAngle - currentRotation));
    currentRotation = rotationAngle;
}
```

(shootDirection is a static int array with 0, 90, 180 and 270)

but the player just looks in the horizontal and vertical directions. When I try to pass in an angle that is not 0,90,180 or 270 degrees it seems to not rotate the image around its center. The image gets cut off, seems to move around some arbitrary axis then the program comes to a grinding halt.

[Image of enemy after a few rotations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUCow.png)

[Original image of enemy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVP4L.png)

I'm not sure why this rotation is working on 90 degree multiples but not on anything else. I've tried changing the player rotations to be slightly off of 0,90,180 and 270 degrees and then I see the same messed up behavior from it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code which draws the rotated image.

Comment: Added a lot more context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 main problems in your code:

### For transformation action, you are transforming the original image, therefore 'destroying' it.

The transformation action is not accurate, and adds inaccuracy (or data loss) with each step. Actually, the `AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR` means that you are doing bilinear interpolation to 'calculate' the new image, which is some kind of 'estimation'. This is why the image becomes more 'blurry' with each iteration.

Instead of doing "increments" over the same image as in

```
enemyImage = cemeteryfuntimes.Code.Shared.Utilities.rotateImage(
        enemyImage, 
        radians - currentRotation);
```

You should keep your original image immutable, never making any changes to it, and for each step, calculate the desired transformation directly from the original image:

```
enemyImage = cemeteryfuntimes.Code.Shared.Utilities.rotateImage(
        sourceEnemyImage,
        currentRotation);
```

### Image is getting truncated

I'm not completely sure why this happens (although looking at `AffineTransformOp` source code I highly suspect it because the affine transformation transform some of the corner no negative coordinates, and for some reason the `createCompatibleDestImage` method choose to take only the positive part), but you can see solutions to other [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10426883/3942452) (which will probably solve your problem, but I haven't found an explanation there).

Another solution for the truncate problem is to have your 'enemy' in the exact middle of a square image which length's is equal (or bigger) to the 'enemy' max diagonal.

### Why works for right angles?

If my guess about negative coordinates is right, it does not apply for right angles. In addition, seems they have [special treatment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#AffineTransform(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double))

Comment: Thank you! Leaving the source image alone makes a lot of sense especially if I'm going to be updating the rotation very frequently. Worked perfectly.

Comment: @user3128305 You welcome. You should accept the answer in that case (and consider upvote it :) )